# codeigniter block me from accesing my phpmyadmin installation on subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, phpmyadmin

I have my own CMS built using CodeIgniter (actually, it's not me who developed it. My client gave it to me from their previous developer). No, I'm in the process of migrating the CMS to a new server. I set it up and everything works fine. Except, I can't access my phpmyadmin installation which reside on the subdirectory of my public_html (which contain the CodeIgniter CMS).

- www.mysite.com *<-- this to access my CodeIgniterCMS based website*
- www.mysite.com/phpmyadmin *<-- this to access my phpmyadmin
  installation, which currently inaccessible and just showing CI's
  default 404 error page*

This might have something to do with CodeIgniter routing configuration or htaccess file and stuff like that. But I'm a total newbie on both CodeIgniter and htaccess.

What should I do to make me able to access my phpmyadmin?

this is my codeigniter htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

let me know what other information (chunk of code, config files etc) should I show here to give better detail of my environment

Answer (score 0):

Your htaccess is not poking a hole through to let access to phpmyadmin.

try

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond $1 !^(phpmyadmin|index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion. Still, apache keeps ignoring that single subfolder and passing it directly to CI controller

Comment: Just to confirm, you do have a folder called phpmyadmin in the root of your website correct? Failing that, try removing the `RewriteBase` line.